# python3 not linked with idle

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pip, python-idle

I have python3.4.0 installed on my system.
Today, I want to install python3.4.3, so I download the source code and install it.
However, my idle is still python3.4.0
while when I type python3 in terminal, it shows python3.4.3.

I also have pandas installed on my old version, it still can be used on my idle (linked with 3.4.0) but not with python3.4.3.

My question is how I can just sticked to python3.4.3 and make everything run in it.

Comment: What kind of system are you using and how did you install Python?  The CPython Windows installer would have replaced 3.4.0 with 3.4.3.  How are you starting Idle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked some questions in a comments.  However, starting Idle with `python3 -m idlelib` will start Idle with whatever python is started with `python3`.  Since you say that `python3` starts 3.4.3, the above should run Idle 3.4.3.